# How does this recursive Javascript function works (Returning the length of a string)

Tags: javascript, recursion, string-length

need some help.

The function returns the length of a string recursively

```
const length = str => str == '' ? 0 : length(str.substring(1)) + 1;
```

It works fine. I have difficulties to understand how the returning of the **length(str.substring(1)) + 1** part works. How does everything gets added up ?. For example input: "Hello World" output: 11. Why doesn't the function concatenate (because of '+' sign) input: "Hello World" output: "Hello World11"?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see `str + ...` anywhere, that would lead to concatenation?

Comment: That's because `length` function here is always returning an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things for explanation, I've rewritten the function to its "long form" below:

```js
function length(str){
  if (str == ''){
    return 0;
  }
  const substr = str.substring(1);
  return length(substr) + 1;
}

console.log(length('abc'));
```

So given input `"abc"`, the steps of execution are as below:

1. Check `'abc' == ''` ==> `false`.
2. Create `substr = 'bc'`.
3. Invoke `length('bc')`:

   1. Check `'bc' == ''` ==> `false`.
   2. Create `substr = 'c'`.
   3. Invoke `length('c')`:

      1. Check `'c' == ''` ===> `false`.
      2. Create `substr = ''`.
      3. Invoke `length('')`:

         1. Check `'' == ''` ===> `true`
         2. Return `0`.
      4. Operate `0 + 1`.
      5. Returns `1`.
   4. Operate `1 + 1`.
   5. Return `2`.
4. Operate `2 + 1`.
5. Return `3`.

As you can see, nowhere in the code would result in a concatenation of string with number.

Answer (score 1):

For example 
    str = "hello" 
,execute the code "length(str)" 
the step as follow

```
    length("hello")
    length("ello") + 1 
    (length("ll") + 1) + 1
    ((length("lo") + 1) + 1) + 1
    (((length("o")+1) + 1) + 1) + 1
    ((((0 + 1)+1) + 1) + 1) + 1
```